# How can a transformed Image transition back to it's original shape when hovered?

Tags: html, css

Hi i'm just a student I just wanna know if its possible to combine hover, transition, and transform by just using css.
How can transformed image transitioned back to it's original size and shape when hovered?

```
<html>
    <style>
      .sample {
          display: inline-block;
          border: 0px solid #fff;
          margin: 10px;
          overflow: hidden;
          height: 500px;
          width: 140px;
          transform: rotate(0deg);
          webkit-transition: 0.8s;
          transition: 0.7s;
      }
      .sample img {
          display: block;
          transform: rotate(2deg);
          transform-origin: 200% -600%;
      }
      .sample img:hover {
          width: 600px;
          height: 600px;
          transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform-origin: 0% 0%;
          -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      }
  </style>
  <body>
      <div class="sample">
          <img src="http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/39/1264-tree.jpg" height="600" width="600">
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only define the CSS "transformed" rules in the hover pseudo-class, then when the image is no longer being hovered-over it will automatically transition back to its original state.

Here is a simplified example using part of your code (I changed the image to the Wikipedia logo since your image was coming up broken):

```css
.sample img {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transition: ease-in-out 700ms;  
}

.sample img:hover {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="sample">
  <img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/project-logos/enwiki.png">
</div>
```

The hover pseudo-class is an "active state class", meaning it only comes into play while that action is taking place (i.e., the pointer is hovered over the element).

If you want to include special easing and timing rules on the change from default state to hovered state then include the `transition` property in the default rule. You can specify lengths of time over which the transition takes place so the change can be more "animated". You'll notice that in the example above I stretched the rotation to 700ms so you can see it turning when hovered, then turning back when no longer hovered.